# "transaction-manager" in "<tx:annotation-driven ... " tag does not get recognized as a valid reference

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

The context is Java Spring MVC and Hibernate, in IntelliJ. For some reason, in the Spring MVC config file, "transaction-manager" is not recognized as a valid reference. See the red text below:

[image: transaction-manager attribute is not allowed here]

Any tips on how to resolve this?

Here is the full config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <!-- Base-package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sprang"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource/Connection Pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.net:3306/heroku_1e4cf119be0ff4a"/>
        <property name="user" value="b3a0c1309826f0"/>
        <property name="password" value="5b30f68e"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sprang.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta put step 4 before step 3.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/><!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: What do you mean with the comment, 'a PlatformTransactionManager is still required'? I placed step 4 before step 3, as shown above. And regarding the comment, '(this dependency is defined somewhere else)', you are referring to the <property name /> tag below it, right? I see that your example would suggest I point to the bean ID I have in Step 1 above -- but not the bean ID I have in Step 2 (Session Factory)?